# Do Nintendo Switch game downloads pause when the console is shut off?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I'm not talking sleep mode, I'm talking completely shut down. Would I have to start downloading from the beginning?

Answer (score 5):

If the Nintendo Switch is completely shut down, it will not continue downloading games or updates.

When this happens, your downloads will pause. When you are able to resume the downloads, they will resume from where you let off; you will not need to completely redownload them from the start.

Alternatively, your Nintendo Switch will be able to download games or updates while it is in sleep mode.

Comment: i'm curious from a technical perspective how sleep mode works. I've noticed with my own switch that I have updates already done and downloaded for me if it's been in sleep mode.

Comment: @TKoL the switch is still technically on while it's in sleep mode, it's just in a lower power state. however things like internet connectivity/downloading still function.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn’t pause. I just updated Rocket League. 20 minutes in, I restarted my console because it needed a software update. When the console turned on again, Rocket League restarted its update.

Comment: Ah that's disappointing. It's a shame nintendo misses so much of this basic stuff